# Delete snapstories from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I am making an app using flutter and I used firestore and storage to store my data.
But the delete button, doesn't work.
What should I change to my code to make it work ? At the time it doesn't do anything.

```
class StoryProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StoryProfileState createState() => _StoryProfileState();
}

class _StoryProfileState extends State<StoryProfile> {
  List<Story> storiesList = [];
  PanelController panelController = PanelController();
  Color bgColor = Colors.transparent;

  String currentUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {
      currentUser = value.uid;
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('Users/$currentUser/Story')
          .getDocuments()
          .then((value) {
        if (value.documents.length == 0) {
          print("No stories");
          panelController.open();
        }
        value.documents.forEach((element) {
          setState(() {
            storiesList.add(
                Story(url: element.data['url'], media: element.data['media']));
          });
        });
      });
      getStoryData();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SlidingUpPanel(
          color: bgColor,
          controller: panelController,
          onPanelOpened: () => setState(() => bgColor = Colors.white),
          onPanelClosed: () => setState(() => bgColor = Colors.transparent),
          panelBuilder: (ScrollController sc) {
            UserPage pg = UserPage();
            pg.scrollController = sc;
            return pg;
          },
          collapsed: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.keyboard_arrow_up,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "SwipeUp to see more information",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                                      

                    RaisedButton(
                     onPressed: (){
                                                         
                    Firestore.instance.collection('Users/$currentUser/Story').document('Stories').delete();
                    },
                    child: Text("Delete"),
                      ),
                                                
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          body: storiesList.length > 0
              ? StoryScreen(stories: storiesList)
              : Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('You didn\'t share any story on profile'),
                  ),
                ),
                
                
                ),
                                     
    );
  }

  void getStoryData() async {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        currentUser = value.uid;
      });
    }).whenComplete(() async {
      QuerySnapshot query = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('Users/$currentUser/Story')
          .getDocuments();
      storiesList.clear();
      if (query.documents.length != 0) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot doc in query.documents) {
          setState(() {
            storiesList.add(Story.fromDocument(doc));
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you expecting that deleting a document from Firestore will also delete it from Storage?  `Firestore.instance.collection......document('Stories').delete()`?

Comment: I expected to delete the video/image added by the user in the app

Comment: Ok. That's not how Firebase works. That path the actual file you have stored in Storage would typically be kept in Firebase (either Firestore or the Realtime Database). When you want to delete the image, you would read the path from the database, delete the image from Storage and then delete the path from Firebase. Here's the Swift version of the documentation for [Delete a File From Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/delete-files#delete_a_file) and there are docs for other platforms as well.